# Конфликт между разными версиями одной и той же зависимой сборки MBS3247 C#

Tags: c#, dll

В проекте необходимо использовать билиотеку NPOI для работы с Excell. Как только добавляю reference, получаю сообщение описанное в заголовке темы. Для работы с файлом .xls был скачан архив в нем:

1. ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib
2. NPOI
3. NPOI.OOXM
4. NPOI.OpenXml4Net
5. NPOI.OpenXmlFormats

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почитал в интернете и решил написать консольную программу для вывода информации о сборке. Использовал FileInfo.GetVersionInfo для каждой из NPOI:

1. 2.0.6
2. 2.0.6
3. 2.0.6
4. 2.0.6.0

Это оно и есть? Другая версия NPOI? Надо найти другой архив с .dll одной версии?

Comment: А Вы попробуйте зависимость (NPOI) установить через NuGet. А то архив это прямо такой олдскул олдскульный)

Comment: @SerafimProzorov, но суть верна?

Comment: Пока не могу понять. Надо больше информации. Ошибка в рантайме происходит? Можете, показать стектрейс?

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке должно быть написано имя этой самой сборки.

Comment: Ошибки нет. То есть, добавил ссылку на сборку и при компиляции пишет предупреждение.

Comment: @AVD, если это просто warning, это не страшно, скорее всего это связано с тем, что у одной из сборок действительно "другая" версия, 2.0.6.0, против 2.0.6. Могу ошибаться.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov, еще раз спасибо.